# Random keyboard malfunction - happens in Vista and XP

Tags: keyboard

For some weird reason, some of my keyboard keys of my deskop are acting very strangely. I don't remember a certain time when it started and I can't recognize any pattern as to when it happens and when it doesn't. The problem occurs in Windows XP, XP Safe Mode, Vista, and Vista Safe mode (I have a dual boot system)  Here's what's happening: 
When I push the I, K, comma, or 8 keys (notice how they are all in the same column), instead of just getting that character, I get extra characters afterwards. For example, I'll push the k key and it will print "ksfda", pushing "I" gives me "IWREQ", comma gives me ", xvcz", pushing 8 gives me "82431".
There are a couple things that I have noticed:

1. It does not happen every time I push the key
2. It happens in all OS and applications I have tested
3. The characters coming after the desired ones are in the same pattern (column order: 2, 4, 3, 1 from the left of the keyboard in the same row as the key pressed.
4. Pressing "]" will sometimes give me "]t", and if done in Notepad, will bring up the "Find" dialog window
5. I cannot seem to remember a specific time the problem started, although I have been defragging, using TuneUp Utilities + CCleaner, and installing lots of new programs lately.

Comment: could it be the keyboard?

Comment: Yeah mate, in the industry we call these "typos"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three possibilities come to mind:

1. You're using a wireless keyboard, and the batteries are getting low.
2. You have a dual-function keyboard and somehow the secondary function is being activated (this is common on laptops without numeric keypads which provide the numeric keypad-style input while a key called "Fn" is pressed or this "Fn" key is effectively *locked* in much the same way CapsLock, NumLock, and ScrollLock can be locked on).
3. Some slob spilled food or drink in your keyboard and didn't bother to tell you about it (if you find out that this was the case, please post a comment back here with their explanation for "why" they didn't bother to let you know -- excuses for laziness can sometimes be very entertaining).